# Logback : best practices with Tomcat and few applications?

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j, logback

We have 12 applications (Java Web & Java SE) which have to use Logback now.
We have some API which factorize some business process. These API are based on Spring with stateless services (@Service & @Autowired)
Applications are deployed in a Tomcat 5.5, API are deployed in shared.
For each application, we have to generate a log by user's session. For that, we are using SiftingAppender / MDC objects.

Which are the best practices in this context ?

1. Manage Slf4j + Logback in each application (lib + logback.xml)
2. Put libs and create a global logback.xml (in classes) of Tomcat's shared ? just for web applications, for Java SE we have to manage it directly.

How to manage MDC correctly ?

We have created a servlet filter, but that's not working very well with Ajax or external thread.
Should we create a new class which for each logging set the MDC with the good value ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is AOP a solution in order to inject the value from Session into MDC ?